# domdocument throws error as "user-defined type not defined" in vb6.0 windows 10, i referred the xml 6.0 in my project

Tags: types, vb6, domdocument, defined, user-defined

In VB 6.0 (Windows 10) I am facing compile time error at `DOMDocument`:

> User-defined type not defined

The same code compiled in XP. I need to know the reason and fix for this issue.

```
Friend Sub Load(xDocvar As DOMDocument)
```

Actual result: it throws error message as "user-defined type not defined".
Expected result: it shouldn't throw error.

Comment: Go to References and see what is MISSING.

Comment: @GSerg is correct. You can also open the VBP in a text editor and view the list of references that it is using. (Don't EDIT it by hand, however)

Answer (score 0):

The XML 6.0 is not exactly backward compatible: some classes now have different names. For example, you should use:

```
Friend Sub Load(xDocvar As DOMDocument60)
```